# What book features a boy who finds out he's the emperor of China?

Tags: story-identification

I read this somewhere around 2006-2008.

The book was about a kid (let's call him "Bob") who finds out he's the emperor of China. He lives with some poor old guy who is secretly some kind of master of a mystical martial art. This old guy gets bitten by a dog on his foot. Bob gets help from "friends" who give the old man some kind of poison (gin). This saves the old man. Then the old man fights some of the evil king's forces to protect Bob, and Bob escapes.

Bob acquires a valuable blade that needs to meet with its opposite half every once in a while to recharge. (Yanglao and Zhizheng?)

Bob's father turns out to be the evil king (of the Mongols?), and he's the "Yin" to Bob's "Yang". He possesses the counterpart to Bob's blade. He kidnaps someone Bob knows (a girl?), and threatens to feed them to some giant sea monster (a lobster?) if Bob doesn't show up. In the end, Bob fights the lobster by heroically flying, and wins, and throws a valuable blade inside the monster.

The back of the book compared it to Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon.

Comment: Did you read it in English? Was a translation? Do you know if it was new when you read it?

Comment: I tried to improve your title, feel free to roll it back or improve it.

Comment: It's was in English, but I don't know if it was a translation. No idea if it was new or anything, but the book's condition seemed somewhere around 2 and 5 years old.

Comment: There was a picture of a kid (Bob, 14+ years old) doing some karate move. (Attacking downwards.)

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [The Book and the Sword](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195907272) by [Louis Cha](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=ntt_athr_dp_sr_1?_encoding=UTF8&sort=relevancerank&search-alias=books&field-author=Louis%20Cha)?

> In the Book and Sword, Louis Cha revives the legend about the great eighteenth-century Manchu Emperor Qianlong which claims that he was in fact not a Manchu but a Han Chinese as a result of a "baby swap". The novel is panoramic in scope and includes the fantastical elements for which Cha is well-known: secret societies, kungfu masters, a lost desert city guarded by wolf packs, and the mysterious Fragrant Princess.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. The description does seem similar to my book, though.